# Linear algebra question: Is my approach valid in saying that

Tags: linear-algebra

let $x$ be an element of $Col(A)$ and $Null(A)$, then there exists a $y$ element of $\Bbb{R}^n$ such that

$Ay = x$
and $Ax = 0$? and then show that $Ay = 0 = x$?
[attached question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vld5.png)

Could really use some help thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the question is correct? If $A^2=I$ you can actually show that $Null(A)=\{0\}$ so of course you'd have that $Null(A)\cap Col(A)=\{0\}$. I thought perhaps that maybe the question was really to show that $Null(A)\cap Col(A)=\{0\}$ assuming that $A^2=A$.

Comment: Statement before link is incorrect $x=e_1, y=e_2$ and $A= \begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$ is an example with $x\neq 0$ ($A^2 \neq I$ so doesnt contradict linked problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've looked at the image linked in the original post. It says that the original problem is:

> Let $A\in M_{n\times n}(\Bbb{R})$ such that $A^2=I$. Prove that $\text{Col}(A)\cap\text{Null}(A)=\left\{0\right\}$.

You're off to a good start. You've let $x\in\text{Col}(A)\cap\text{Null}(A)$. From the fact that $x\in\text{Null}(A)$ we have that

$$Ax=0.$$

From the fact that $x\in\text{Col}(A)$ we have that

$$x=Ay$$
for some $y\in\Bbb{R}^n$. You'll be done if you can use these facts to show that $x=\vec{0}$.

In general, if you get stuck solving a problem, one way to get unstuck is to ask, "What was I given that I haven't used yet?" In this case, you haven't yet used the fact $A^2=I$. If you haven't already done so, I think it would be a good idea to take some time to see if you can prove $x=0$ using the fact that $A^2=I$.

In case you're still stuck, here's one way to do it:

> Note that $$y=Iy=A^2y=A(Ay)=Ax=0.$$ And since $y=0$, it follows that $$x=Ay=A0=0.$$

Answer (score 0):

The attached question has probably a typo. If $A^2=I$, then $A$ is invertible and therefore $\operatorname{Null}(A)=\{0\}$, so clearly $\operatorname{Col}(A)\cap\operatorname{Null}(A)=\{0\}$ as well.

Indeed, if $x\in\operatorname{Null}(A)$, then $Ax=0$, so $A(Ax)=A0=0$; but $A^2=I$ implies $Ix=0$, that is, $x=0$.

A more sensible question would be:

> prove that if $A^2=A$, then $\operatorname{Col}(A)\cap\operatorname{Null}(A)=\{0\}$

In order to prove it, let $x\in\operatorname{Col}(A)\cap\operatorname{Null}(A)=\{0\}$. Then $x=Ay$ and $Ax=0$, so
$$
0=Ax=A^2x=A(Ax)=Ay=x
$$